# Passing value from inner fragment to outer fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am working on creating a form which is a fragment(layout) in an activity.In the form i have input fields which is use to select date and time.I am populating the date and  time using the datepicker dialog fragment which is a seperate fragment.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

I am facing the problem as how to update the input field in my form fragment from the datepicker fragment.I did try this approach but i get null value.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html

Also is the above method the right approach or should i add the date picker fragment as an inner class in my form fragment connsidering i may not use datepicker elsewhere.

PS: I am a noob.Any help will be greatly appreciated.

**Solution**:

Since I was using a fragmentpageradapter, In my inner fragment i generated the list of fragments using this

```
List<fragment> fragmentList = this.getFragmentManager().getFragments();
```

Created a singleton class and added a method
    /*Getting form fragment*/

```
 public Fragment getMyEventFragment(List<Fragment> fragmentList){
            Fragment myEventFragment =null;

                for (int i = 0; i < fragmentList.size(); i++) {
                    String currentTag = fragmentList.get(i).getTag();
                    String lastChar = currentTag.substring(currentTag.length() - 1);
                    System.out.println("the lastchar is " + lastChar);
                    if (lastChar.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        myEventFragment = fragmentList.get(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            return myEventFragment;
     }
```

Since my form fragment was in the second tab in my fragmentpageradapater the value is 1 as the last element in a autogenerated fragment tag refers to the fragment position.

Once i obtained my form fragment i could update the corresponding input field values.

Comment: Add tags to fragment and use `findFragmentByTag`

Comment: I am using fragment pager adapter to create the fragment .How do i add the tag name there?

Comment: @PedroOliveira Your suggestion gave me some pointers.Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

set tag for each fragment to enable call them

How to set Fragment TAG , you can only add tag to fragment while transaction

```
// getSupportFragmentManager() if you use support library 
 // tag is optional , but you should assign one to call it again 
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, fragment, "your_tag").commit();


   // you can call it any where you want 
    android.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();                
    FirstFragment fragment = (FirstFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag( "your_tag" );
    // use fragment to do what ever you want 
    fragment.update(string);
```

there anther example how to determine fragment but this time by id

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <fragment class="com.example.android.apis.app.FragmentLayout$TitlesFragment"
            android:id="@+id/titles"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</FrameLayout>
```

fragment id here is **titles** `android:id="@+id/titles"`

when i want to call it

```
TitlesFragment titles= (TitlesFragment)
     getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.titles);
```

this works if your fragment identifier in XML

Comment: Hi my problem was that I didnt know the tag value of the fragment.Hence i initially wanted a mean to set the fragment tag value.I am currently relying on autogenerated tag generated by fragmentpageradpater.

Comment: @rahulinaction I edit answer please have a look and let me know if this work with you